PrimeNG Style issue when using theme css file with imports rather than injection
When I use primeng themes via injecting the stylesheets in angular.json, I get the result I am looking for which is shown below.
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-dark-blue/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ]


When I don't inject the themes, but rather put them in a theme-dark.css file which I then link in the index.html, I get a different result with missing styles...

"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          {
            "input": "src/assets/themes/theme-light.css",
            "bundleName": "theme-light",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "src/assets/themes/theme-dark.css",
            "bundleName": "theme-dark",
            "inject": false
          }
        ]

The theme-dark.css file contains the following:
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-dark-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.css";

Here is my styles.css file since I am also using Tailwind:


@import "primeflex/primeflex.min.css";
@import "primeicons/primeicons.css";

@layer tailwind-base, primeng, tailwind-utilities;

@layer tailwind-base {
  @tailwind base;
}

@layer tailwind-utilities {
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
}

p-password.w-full {
  .p-password, .p-password-mask, .p-password-input {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}

.dark-toggle.p-inputswitch {
  .p-inputswitch-slider::before {
    margin-top: -12px;
    background: transparent;
    content: "";
  }
}
.dark-toggle.p-inputswitch-checked .p-inputswitch-slider::before {
  content: "";
}



Essentially, I want the first image's results but without the injection of the styles within the angular.json, so the themes of primeng and colors can be changed on the fly...

please share the github repo or stackblitz example with the issue happening and steps to replicate the issue

This can be replicated by starting an Angular project with Tailwind and PrimeNG
